# Find the derivative of $f(x)=x^{k-1}exp(-ax^k)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I want to find the first derivative of

$$f\colon(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}, a > 0, k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

$$f(x)=x^{k-1}\exp(-ax^k)$$

So I applied the product rule and got the first derivative as:

$$f'(x)=\left(x^{k-2}\right)\left(k-1\right)\left(e^{-ax^k}\right) - \left(akx^{2k-2}\right)\left(e^{-ax^k}\right)$$

And I think that's it but I can't help but feel that the domain and the range of the function may change or have an impact on the derivative.

Comment: You're fine. Nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you face expressions containing only products, quotients, powers, logarithmic differentiation makes life easier.

For your case
$$f=x^{k-1}\exp(-ax^k)\implies \log(f)=(k-1)\log(x)-ax^k$$
$$\frac {f'}f=\frac {k-1} x-ak x^{k-1}$$ Now, use $$f'=f \times \frac {f'}f$$ and simplify as much as you can.

If you are concerned by programming, this would be the cheapest way to compute the derivative since $$\frac {f'}f=\frac{(k-1)-akx^k}x$$ contains most of the terms which were required for the computation of $f$.